# Integrate Azure web app to Cortana

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana

I have created a web app with the name shipBot. I have already integrated with the skype but now i need to integrate with the cortana. If anyone knows please let me know as the documentation given is outdated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBaR.png)

Comment: Try to create an MSA account and see if it helps. Also, try to refer the workaround from this GitHub link: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3658. Reference: https://help.knowledge.store/getting_started/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to create Microsoft account to [connect a bot to Cortana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-cortana?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) as mentioned in the image you shared. If you are using a Microsoft account and the issue still persists, share your Email Id so that we can investigate further.

Also to invoke the Cortana, you have to [set up your device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/mva21-setup#step-3---set-up-your-cortana-device) with the same Microsoft account that you used to register the skill.

Comment: Yes it worked. Now i am able to get the options to integrate with the cortana.

Comment: but after completing all the steps given in the documentation, bot is not getting invoked from cortana. Can you please provide me the detailed steps with screenshots to connect it with cortana

Comment: Are you using your desktop cortana through MSA account with which you've connected Cortana?

Comment: yeah i am using the same account in desktop cortana and with same MSA i have created bot in azure